# How to extract results from a yahoo search?

Tags: php, search, web-scraping, yahoo-api

I need to pass all the results retrieved by a yahoo search with an URL like that:

https://es.search.yahoo.com/search?p=madrid&fr=yfp-t-777

and display them like this.

[image]

Comment: https://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/ API is better than trying to parse the page for 2 reasons: the page can change and it's against Yahoo's policy

Answer (score 1):

You can scrape data from yahoo using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/packages/jsoup-1.8.3.jar)
Here is the code using Jsoup to parse all the result from yahoo search with the URL you give

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String url = "https://es.search.yahoo.com/search?p=madrid&fr=yfp-t-777";
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Getting data from " + url);
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(10000).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").get();
            Elements sections = doc.select("ol.searchCenterMiddle").first().select("div.options-toggle");
            if (sections.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
            for (Element section : sections) {
                try {
                    System.out.println(section.getElementsByTag("a").first().text());
                    System.out.println(section.getElementsByTag("span").first().text() + " " + section.select("a.tri").first().text());
                    System.out.println();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
            url = doc.select("a.next[href]").attr("href");
        }
}
```

Comment: @javipedrera did my answer solve your problem ? if did why don't you accept my answer ?